# TextBoxFor extesion with formatted value shows 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I can't use EditorFor because my inputs have some other attributes like `readonly`, `disable` and `class` therefor i am using an extension for TextBoxFor. I need to display formatted numeric value so my extension method is defined as

```
public static MvcHtmlString FieldForAmount<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    MvcHtmlString html = default(MvcHtmlString);
    Dictionary<string, object> newHtmlAttrib = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    newHtmlAttrib.Add("readonly", "readonly");
    newHtmlAttrib.Add("class", "lockedField amountField");

    var _value = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, 
                     htmlHelper.ViewData).Model;
    newHtmlAttrib.Add("value", string.Format(Formats.AmountFormat, value));

    html = System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(htmlHelper, 
        expression, newHtmlAttrib);
    return html;
}
```

`Formats.AmountFormat` is defined as `"{0:#,##0.00##########}"`.

Lets say `_value` is 2,  `newHtmlAttrib` shows it as `2.00` but the resultant `html` shows `0`, it always shows `0` regardless of any value.
Where am i wrong or what can i do to get it fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `TextBox` helper if you want to specify a format:

```
public static MvcHtmlString FieldForAmount<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
)
{
    var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "readonly", "readonly" },
        { "class", "lockedField amountField" },
    };

    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    var value = string.Format(Formats.AmountFormat, metadata.Model);
    var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    var fullHtmlFieldName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);

    return htmlHelper.TextBox(fullHtmlFieldName, value, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: I cant see `TextBox` in `HtmlHelper`

Comment: i think you mean `System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox(htmlHelper, fullHtmlFieldName, value, htmlAttributes);`

Comment: Yes, it worked. May i know why `TextBoxFor` is accepting htmlAttributes but not using its `value` attribute?

Comment: @bjan, you can't see `TextBox` in `HtmlHelper` because you didn't brought the extension method into scope by adding `using System.Web.Mvc.Html` to your file. No, I didn't mean `System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox(htmlHelper, fullHtmlFieldName, value, htmlAttributes);` at all. I have changed that on purpose. As far as why the `TextBoxFor` helper doesn't allow changing the `value` attribute, well, that's by design => it uses the value of the model property specified in the lambda expression passed as first argument.

Comment: OK. It looks `htmlHelper.TextBox` and `Html.InputExtensions.TextBox` are not different w.r.t. their calling in this extension as these are producing the same html

Comment: Yes, they are exactly the same. It's just that the correct way to invoke an extension method is to do this on an instance of the class it is extending and not call the static method directly.